# Resizing .rdl report inside ReportViewer control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, rdl, reportviewer

My .rdl report has columns of a fixed size and in preview mode of bi dev studio it looks ok. When viewed in ReportViewer control on asp.net site it shrinks. How can I make it always fill the size of the reportViewer control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to place the table in a rectangle element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should set it in the report itself - by clicking the textBox in the properties you should select CanShrink to false.

Comment: well it doesn't work. the columns still shrink if they have no data

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to place the tablix control in a rectangle element.